# Problem with position of float

Tags: floats, sectioning

I don't understand why does the float object appears above `/section{}`. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % Manejo de idiomas
\usepackage[pages = some]{background} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ieee, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\addbibresource{Anteproyecto.bib}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
%\usepackage{nomencl}
%\makenomenclature
%%\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}

\backgroundsetup{
contents={\includegraphics{escudounipamplona.png}},
angle=0, 
scale=0.45, 
color=black, 
opacity=0.1
}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Lista de tablas}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{M{#1}}

\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,top=4cm,headheight=75pt,footskip=65pt]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.95cm}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancyhead[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all headers
\fancyhead[C]{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|M{3.0cm}|X|M{2.5cm}|M{3cm}|}
    \hline
    \multirow{4}*{\includegraphics[scale=0.034]{escudounipamplona}}
    &
    \multirow{4}*{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering Propuesta trabajo de grado para optar por el título de Ingeniero en Mecatrónica}}
    &
    \multirow{2}*{\textbf{C\'odigo}}
    &
    \multirow{2}*{1.2}\\
    &&&
    \\\cline{3-4}
    &&
    \multirow{2}*{\textbf{Pagina}}
    &
    \multirow{2}*{\small\emph{Pagina \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}}\hspace{15pt}}\\
    &&&\\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
}

\begin{document}
\BgThispage
\begin{center}
{
\Large\textbf{Realización de planes de mantenimiento basados en ingeniería de confiabilidad y propuesta de ingeniería para la mejora operacional a equipos electromecánicos del Hospital Erasmo Meoz de Cúcuta: Informe de Practica Laboral}  
\vspace{5cm}
\\
{\normalsize \textit{Autor}} \\
Juan David Bola\~nos Aguilar\\

\vspace{5cm}
Programa de ingenier\'ia mecatr\'onica \\
Departamento de ingenier\'ia mec\'anica, mecatr\'onica e industrial \\
Facultad de ingenierías y arquitectura\\
Universidad de Pamplona\\
Villa del Rosario, Norte de Santander\\
febrero del 2015\\
}
\end{center}
\newpage
\BgThispage
\begin{center}
{

\large\textbf{Realización de planes de mantenimiento basados en ingeniería de confiabilidad y propuesta de ingeniería para la mejora operacional a equipos electromecánicos del Hospital Erasmo Meoz de Cúcuta: Informe de Practica Laboral}  
\vspace{2cm}
\\
{\small \textit{Autor}} \\
Juan David Bola\~nos Aguilar \\
{\small \textit{Codigo: 1116249797}} \\
{\small\textit{Correo electronico: judabo@unipamplona.edu.co}} \\
\vspace{1cm}
{\small \textit{Director}} \\
Dr. Rocco Tarantino Alvarado \\
{\small\textit{Doctorado en Ciencias Aplicadas}} 
\\
{\small \textit{Correo electronico: rocco.tarantino@unipamplona.edu.co}} \\
\vspace{1cm}
{\small\textit{Supervisor}} \\
Ing. Rafael Antonio Sepulveda Ayala \\
{\small \textit{Coord. de mantenimiento, Hospital Universitario Erasmo Meoz}} 
\\
{\normalsize \textit{Correo electronico: blablabla@erasmo.co}}\\
\vspace{2cm}
Programa de ingenier\'ia mecatr\'onica \\
Departamento de ingenier\'ia mec\'anica, mecatr\'onica e industrial \\
Facultad de ingenierías y arquitectura\\
Universidad de Pamplona\\
Villa del Rosario, Norte de Santander\\
febrero del 2015\\
}
\end{center}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\newpage

\section{INTRODUCCI\'ON}
\vspace{2cm}
El Hospital Universitario Erasmo Meoz es el centro de salud más importante de Norte de Santander. Con categoría nivel cuarto de complejidad, su nombre es en homenaje a Erasmo Meoz Wills, primer medico oriundo del departamento quien murió el 1 de junio de 1918 y cuyos restos descansan en la entrada del edificio. La fundación del hospital data del año 1987 y concentra un volumen significativo de servicios de salud que abarcan todas las especialidades medicas. A nivel ingenieril representa un reto en lo que a su funcionamiento se refiere; consta de aproximadamente 2500 dispositivos médicos y complejas instalaciones dedicadas a servicios como el de lavandería, alimentación y mantenimiento de equipos, entre otros.
\newline\par
Un despliegue logístico de tal envergadura implica alta sensibilidad en aspectos tales como costos de mantenimiento, operación y  eficiencia energética que juntos tienen una participación significativa en la dinámica que presenta el movimiento de recursos económicos disponibles. El objetivo de esta practica empresarial es abordar desde el enfoque ingenieril propuestas encaminadas a plantear un manejo optimo de recursos a nivel energético y de costos de mantenimiento mediante una serie de actividades que abarcan dichas temáticas. Tales actividades se resumen en propuestas para la mejora de planes de mantenimiento, optimización  de la iluminación eléctrica en corredores y mejoras en equipos del área de lavandería. 

\newpage
\section{JUSTIFICACIÓN}
\vspace{2cm}
Uno de los grandes problemas que presenta el sector de salud en Colombia esta relacionado con la carencia de recursos económicos destinados a planes de modernización y mejoramiento de la planta física de las instituciones publicas que prestan servicios sanitarios. Por lo general, una planta física moderna se traduce en un manejo energético optimo y en mejoras relacionadas con la calidad de los servicios de salud prestados a la comunidad, por lo tanto es imperativo destinar fondos a planes que favorezcan dichas condiciones. Como se menciono con anterioridad, los recursos económicos para tales planes son reducidos, en consecuencia no solo es necesario implementar planes de adecuación tecnológica,  también es fundamental que las propuestas realizadas sean económicas y no representen una inversión significativa para la institución puesto que en este caso siempre hay otros elementos que requieren una mayor prioridad. 
\newline\par
Con la presente practica se busca plantear una propuesta de mejora a dos aspectos claves en lo que se refiere a reducción de costos operacionales del hospital  Erasmo Meoz; el manejo energético y los planes de mantenimiento de equipos. Con el fin de concretar las actividades a realizar se ha seleccionado una serie de actividades que  se basaran en estos dos aspectos. El fin ultimo de la practica es contribuir con el bienestar general de los usuarios del centro hospitalario y del personal en general, en particular de aquel que esta vinculado directamente con el área de mantenimiento del hospital, ademas de aportar mejoras técnicas y operacionales contribuyendo al desarrollo tecnológico de la institución.

\newpage
\section{PLANTEAMIENTO DEL PROBLEMA}
\vspace{2cm}
Las actividades propuestas como directrices de la presente practica empresarial y que se pretenden desarrollar a lo largo de la misma son inicialmente tres. Inicialmente se presenta la necesidad de mejorar el sistema de control que emplean los compresores de aire instalados en el área de lavandería; su actuación es mecánica y se espera hacer la transición a una actuación electrónica, ademas se requiere que su funcionamiento sea de tal modo que ayude a preservar la vida útil de los equipos. De igual modo, se debe plantear una estrategia de optimizacion energética para la iluminación eléctrica de los corredores del primer piso del hospital que implique no solo una disminución de consumo  eléctrico sino que a su vez ofrezca confort tanto a personal medico como a pacientes. Por ultimo es necesario realizar una revisión y consecuente mejora al plan de mantenimiento de una serie de equipos previamente seleccionados entre los que podemos encontrar la planta de respaldo energético, las calderas y las secadoras de la lavandería; el objetivo es modernizar dichos planes de mantenimiento y verificar que se encuentran ajustados a la normativa vigente.  

\newpage
\section{OBJETIVO GENERAL}
\vspace{2cm}
\begin{center}
Realizar planes de mantenimiento basados en ingeniería de confiabilidad y plantear una propuesta de ingeniería para la mejora operacional a equipos electromecánicos del Hospital Erasmo Meoz de Cúcuta
\end{center}

\newpage
\section{OBJETIVOS ESPECÍFICOS}
\vspace{2cm}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Realizar  el acopio de información, la caracterización de las actividades a realizar y la ingeniería básica de dichas actividades.
    \item Diseñar la ingeniería de detalle de los compresores de lavandería y el sistema de iluminación de  los pasillos.
    \item Realizar planes de mantenimiento para las calderas, la planta de respaldo energético y las secadoras.
\end{enumerate}

\newpage
\section{PLAN DE TRABAJO}
\vspace{2cm}
El plan de trabajo estará fundamentado en la resolución secuencial de cada uno de los objetivos específicos planteados con anterioridad. Se estima una duración total de entre 16 semanas y se espera dedicar en general un  total de 4 a 6 semanas por objetivo.
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X | X | X |}
\hline
\textbf{Objetivo especifico}     & \textbf{Metas}     & \textbf{Indicador}             &\textbf{Actividades}\\ 
\hline
Realizar  el acopio de información, la caracterización de las actividades a realizar y la ingeniería básica de dichas actividades.         
&\begin{itemize}
    \item Documentar todas las actividades a realizar
    \item Realizar una descripción completa de las actividades realizando el levantamiento del problema 
    \item Diseñar la ingeniería básica requerida por cada una de las actividades 
\end{itemize}         
&
NOTA: Determinar indicador             
&
NOTA: Determinar actividades\\ 
\hline
Diseñar la ingeniería de detalle de los compresores de lavandería y el sistema de iluminación de  los pasillos.
&
\begin{itemize}
    \item Determinar el sistema de control que se debe implementar en los compresores de lavandería.
    \item Proponer y justificar un esquema de iluminación optimo para las luces de pasillos y áreas comunes del primer piso del Hospital.
\end{itemize}
&
NOTA: Determinar indicador             
&
NOTA: Determinar actividades        
\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Plan de actividades. \label{tab:table_label}}
\end{table}

\clearpage
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X | X | X |}
    \hline
    \textbf{Objetivo especifico}     & \textbf{Metas}     & \textbf{Indicador}             &\textbf{Actividades}     \\ \hline
    Actualizar los planes de mantenimiento de las calderas, la planta de respaldo energético y las secadoras.
    &
    Verificar que el planes de mantenimiento vigente para calderas, la planta de respaldo energético y las secadoras se encuentra actualizado y es el optimo. En caso contrario, proponer un nuevo plan de mantenimiento que se ajuste a estas condiciones.
    &
    NOTA: Determinar indicador             
    &
    NOTA: Determinar actividades         
    \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Plan de actividades, continuacion. \label{tab:table_label}}

\end{table}

\clearpage
\section{CRONOGRAMA DE ACTIVIDADES}
\vspace{2cm}
\begin{table}
\begin{ganttchart}{1}{16}
    \gantttitle{Cronograma de actividades}{16} \\
    \gantttitlelist{1,...,16}{1} \\
    \ganttgroup{Objetivo 1}{1}{4} \\
    \ganttbar{Actividad 1}{1}{2} \\
    \ganttlinkedbar{Actividad 2}{3}{4}\ganttnewline
    \ganttmilestone{Milestone}{7}\ganttnewline
    \ganttbar{Objetivo final}{8}{12}
    \ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
    \ganttlink{elem3}{elem4}
\end{ganttchart}
\caption{Cronograma de actividades.}\label{tab:table_label}
\end{table}


%\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And this is the behavior that I don't understand:

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use `\begin{table}[htb]` and then it comes correct.

Comment: @HarishKumar What is [htb]?

Comment: `h` = here, `t` = top, `b` = bottom.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, you could give some placement commands to the float environment. Or you just set the diagram inside a `center` environment:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % get rid of demo here.
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[pages = some]{background} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
% sets the page style of the first chapter page from plain to fancy
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}

\backgroundsetup{
    contents={\includegraphics{escudounipamplona.png}},
    angle=0, 
    scale=0.45, 
    color=black, 
    opacity=0.1
}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Lista de tablas}
% defines the chapter command to your taste. No need of \clearpage anymore
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{1em}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{M{#1}}

\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,top=4cm,headheight=75pt,footskip=65pt]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.95cm}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancyhead[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all headers
\fancyhead[C]{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|M{3.0cm}|X|M{2.5cm}|M{3cm}|}
        \hline
        \multirow{4}*{\includegraphics[scale=0.034]{escudounipamplona}}
        &
        \multirow{4}*{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering Propuesta trabajo de grado para optar por el título de Ingeniero en Mecatrónica}}
        &
        \multirow{2}*{\textbf{C\'odigo}}
        &
        \multirow{2}*{1.2}\\
        &&&
        \\\cline{3-4}
        &&
        \multirow{2}*{\textbf{Pagina}}
        &
        \multirow{2}*{\small\emph{Pagina \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}}\hspace{15pt}}\\
        &&&\\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
}
% You can remove the following two lines. Have a look on the numbering of the table!
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\usepackage{hyperref} % should be last package in most cases

\begin{document}
% get rid of the following two lines
\setcounter{chapter}{6}
\setcounter{table}{2}
\chapter{Cronograma de actividades}
\begin{center}
    \begin{ganttchart}{1}{16}
        \gantttitle{Cronograma de actividades}{16} \\
        \gantttitlelist{1,...,16}{1} \\
        \ganttgroup{Objetivo 1}{1}{4} \\
        \ganttbar{Actividad 1}{1}{2} \\
        \ganttlinkedbar{Actividad 2}{3}{4}\ganttnewline
        \ganttmilestone{Milestone}{7}\ganttnewline
        \ganttbar{Objetivo final}{8}{12}
        \ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
        \ganttlink{elem3}{elem4}
    \end{ganttchart}
    \captionof{table}{Cronograma de actividades.}\label{tab:table_label}
\end{center}
\section{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\end{document}
```

[image]